# Fraction power and fraction of logs

Tags: inequality, logarithms

> For $1>x>y>0$ and $n\geq 1$, prove $$\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^n \geq \frac{\ln y}{\ln x}.$$

Attempt: Rewrote it as $$x^n \ln(x)- y^n \ln y\leq 0$$

Tried to show that the LHS is quasi-convex in $n$ and that it attains its lowest value for $n\leq 1$.

Got a bit more complicated.

Comment: That seems to be wrong, $x \mapsto x^n \ln(x)$ is *not* a monotonic function on $(0, 1)$.

Comment: This inequality is false for $n=1, x= \frac{2}{3}, y = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: It will be true only for $y>\frac{1}{e}$

Comment: Indeed, thanks guys